# Using OpenSSH on Windows for enterprise use

Tags: windows, cygwin, openssh

Is OpenSSH for Windows (using Cygwin) considered robust & stable for enterprise use?

Comment: Better suited to superuser.com?

Answer (score 0):

The ssh client works fine for me, and has for a long time. The ssh daemon has been a different story, but to be fair, I haven't tried it in a few years.